# Нужна или нет запятая перед "как" ("Он погиб как герой")?

Tags: пунктуация, сравнительный-оборот, оборот-с-как

Нужна ли запятая в предложении "Он погиб как герой"?

Answer (score 1):

1. Вот что говорится в теории.

Обороты *с союзом **как*** не выделяются запятыми, если на первый план выступает значение обстоятельства образа действия (обороты с **как** можно заменить в этих случаях формой творительного падежа существительного или наречием).
***Как град***  посыпалась картечь (ср.: *посыпалась градом*);
*Он умер  **как настоящий герой*** (*умер настоящим героем*).

2. Практика же такова.

У М. Ю. Лермонтова: *Она ускользнёт, **как змея,** порхнёт и умчится, **как птичка.***
Можно допустить, что автору важно было создать художественные образы путем чистого сравнения (*подобно змее, подобно птичке*; хотя сравнение сохраняется и в сочетаниях *ускользнёт змеёй, умчится птичкой,* но с добавочным оттенком образа действия).

Поэтому некоторые предложения допускают двоякое толкование и, следовательно, двоякую пунктуацию; ср.: *Он умер,  **как настоящий герой*** (*подобно настоящему герою*).

[§ 42. Сравнительный оборот](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827524.html) (Д. Э. Розенталь)

3. Справочник по подготовке к ЕГЭ (В. Татарова) рекомендует в устойчивом словосочетании ***умер как герой*** запятую [не ставить](https://books.google.ee/books?id=nbSKDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA116&lpg=PA116&dq=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B1%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F&source=bl&ots=08_1EIf7Ef&sig=ACfU3U33pTmYNZmxuH8ZWg4zN4MMSHkeMg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwir5Mj-2MzhAhXKAxAIHXOYCxQ4ChDoATABegQICBAB#v=onepage&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B1%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F&f=false).
   Чаще всего она не ставится и в выражении ***погиб как герой.***

[**«Летал, как бог. Погиб как герой»**](https://tvzvezda.ru/news/vstrane_i_mire/content/201703280758-lmrv.htm)
*Максим Плетнев погиб как герой, в Сирии, при выполнении боевого задания.*
*Российский лётчик погиб как герой, расстреляв около 40 патронов...*